# Connecting to MySQL Server on Ubuntu not possible

Tags: php, mysql, windows, ubuntu, workbench

I have set up a raspberry PI 4 with Ubuntu. Apache, PHP, mysql and phpmyadmin are installed and working fine. So when I am trying to connect from another network with my windows device over MySQL Workbench there is an error occuring.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA4zk.png)

Checked: port forwarding on port 80 is open. checked binding ip in mysqld.conf (maybe I made a mistake there) when I try to change the port in this configuration file to 80 and restart "sudo service mysql restart" this error occure "Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code"

So maybe mysql is not listening to port 80. I have checked sudo lsof -i :80. Only found records from apache listening to port 80.

I am trying for three days now to connect to the database.

Thank you for your help guys!

Comment: also changed auth mode to native

Comment: If you want more information. Just tell me which files or which logs you need.

Comment: Is there any code involved you want to share? Why is this question tagged with PHP, Windows, Ubuntu, and Wordpress, but does not contain any information about what **exactly** is not working? Also, please share your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: I solved the problem by opening another port. I would like to post more code, but I am developing a tool for someone. This person don't want me to make parts of the code public. This was the reason for describing the problem without posting code. 
Thank you for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

By default, mysql listens on port 3306, so if you are trying to connect directly to mysql, that could be the issue. Port 80 and 443 are for http/https respectively.

You can't set the port to port 80 because apache needs that port to listen for http requests.

Try setting the port back to 3306 on the mysql host machine and seeing if that works. You may also need to open that port on the host machine as well.

Comment: Thank you ! I am going to try it and give you feedback..

Comment: I tried to open new port forwarding on port 3306 to check if there is a connection directly to MySQL. It worked nice! Thank you so much for your knowledge!

Comment: And I tried to connect and made SELECT QUERIES over http requests on port 80. 
That worked too. Thank you Mr. Brown! :D